# why result of grouping join repeat 2 times?

Tags: c#, linq

I write a grouping join between 2 collection
1-student
2-madrak
each madrak have many student and each student have one madrak
in other word there is one to many relation between to table

result of grouping join is 
![group join]:(https://pasteboard.co/IibmzbL.jpg)

that repeat 2 time.
i can not understand why we have 4 group

```
namespace ConsoleApp4{
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
                                {
                                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName 
                                  = "davod zarei", MadrakID =1 },
                                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName 
                                = "eshrat alipour", MadrakID =1 },
                                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName 
                                = "hadi pournader", MadrakID =2 },
                                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName 
                                = "mahdi chegini", MadrakID =2 },
                                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName 
                                 = "Bozorg Mirzahoseini"}
                               };
        IList<Madrak> madrakList = new List<Madrak>()
                                {
                                new Madrak(){ MadrakID = 1, 
                                 MadrakName="lisance"},
                                new Madrak(){ MadrakID = 2, 
                                MadrakName="arshad"},
                                new Madrak(){ MadrakID = 3, 
                                MadrakName="phd"},
                                };
       var GroupJoinResult2 =
             from md in madrakList
             join  stu in studentList
             on md.MadrakID  equals stu.MadrakID into MachedStudent
             from item in MachedStudent
             select new { Key = md.MadrakID, Items = MachedStudent };
      Console.WriteLine("---------- group Join  Result ----------");
      foreach (var item in GroupJoinResult2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":");
            foreach (var element in item.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   " + element.StudentName);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int MadrakID { get; set; }
}

public class Madrak
{
    public int MadrakID { get; set; }
    public string MadrakName { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code has a serious formatting problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can not understand why we have 4 group

You have made a really weird combination of a group join and a regular join by confusing the group of students with a single student.

Let's go through it in detail.

I'll simplify your code. Let's start by making a simplified Student type:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(string s, string m) 
    {
        StudentName = s;
        MadrakName = m;
    }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string MadrakName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return StudentName; }
}
```

And a school can be just a string. So now we have four students and three schools:

```
    var studentList = new List<Student>() {
        new Student("S1", "M1"),
        new Student("S2", "M1"),
        new Student("S3", "M2"),
        new Student("S4", "M2")
    };
    var madrakList = new List<string>() { "M1", "M2", "M3" };
```

The third school has no students.

What do we want? We want a list of the lists of the students of each school. That is, we should get three lists; the first list should be S1 and S2, the second should be S3 and S4, and the third should be empty:

```
    var q =
         from m in madrakList
         join s in studentList
         on m equals s.MadrakName into MatchedStudent
         select MatchedStudent;
```

Now let's print out each of those:

```
   foreach(var item in q)
       Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(",", item) + "}");
```

And we get what we want:

```
{S1,S2}
{S3,S4}
{}
```

There are three schools, so you should get three rows in your group join.

Now, why did you get the results you got with your query? **You turned your group join back into a regular join**.  Let's try a variation on your query:

```
         from m in madrakList
         join s in studentList
         on m equals s.MadrakName into MatchedStudent
         from item in MatchedStudent
         select new { Key = m, Items = item };
```

`item` takes on values S1, S2, S3, S4, and this says to make a tuple where the key is the school, `m`, and the item is the student.  All you've done is a really complicated way of writing

```
         from m in madrakList
         join s in studentList
         on m equals s.MadrakName 
         select new { Key = m, Items = s }
```

That is, a normal join, not a group join. Obviously there are four rows to that because they are:

```
M1, S1
M1, S2
M2, S3
M2, S4
```

There are four students with schools, so there should be four rows in your normal join.

But that is not what you wrote. You wrote

```
         from m in madrakList
         join s in studentList
         on m equals s.MadrakName into MatchedStudent
         from item in MatchedStudent
         select new { Key = m, Items = MatchedStudent }; 
         // MatchedStudent is a list of students!
```

So now what have you got? Instead of

```
M1, S1
M1, S2
M2, S3
M2, S4
```

Where we have a student in the column, instead we have **all the matching students in the column:**

```
M1, {S1, S2} // From S1
M1, {S1, S2} // From S2
M2, {S3, S4} // From S3
M2, {S3, S4} // From S4
```

Basically, you've written a really weird combination of a regular join and a group join. The table has the form of a regular join, with four rows, one for each student with a school, but each "student" in the row is *the entire list of matching students from the group*.

It looks like you got confused and forgot that `MatchedStudent` is a *list of students*, because it is a group join. You were treating it like it was a student, but that's wrong too.

Likely the code you intended to write was:

```
    var q =
         from m in madrakList
         join s in studentList
         on m equals s.MadrakName into studentsInMadrak
         select new { Madrak = m, Students = studentsInMadrak };
   foreach(var item in q)
       Console.WriteLine(item.Madrak + "{" +  
         string.Join(",", item.Students) + "}");
```

Which prints out

```
M1{S1,S2}
M2{S3,S4}
M3{}
```

Does that all make sense?